# ¿Como instalar CERTBOT en EC2 Linux 2?

Tags: nodejs, linux, certbot

Tengo una instancia de amazon Linux 2 en donde tengo instalado Node, quiero instalarle Certbot, para ello estoy realizando el procedimiento que se indica aqui:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-an-instance.html#letsencrypt

El problema lo estoy teniendo en el paso 2 en el que tengo que editar el archivo `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, archivo que no tengo porque no he instalado Apache y por consiguiente los pasos siguientes tambien me presentan error.

Lo que necesito es instalar los certificados ssl y configurar para que se renueve automaticamente. ¿Esto se puede hacer?. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Depende de que servidor tengas instalado. Si tienes `nginx` puedes correr algo del estilo.

```
$ sudo certbot --nginx -d nombre_de_dominio1 -d nombre_de_dominio2
```

Si es apache, entonces.

```
$ sudo certbot --apache -d nombre_de_dominio ...
```

Para que se renueve, puedes probar con con crontab.

```
$ sudo crontab -e
```

Y dentro del crontab poner algo como.

```
0 0 */1 * * certbot renew --renew-hook 'service nginx reload'
```

Y se renueva cada cada día a las 0:00 horas de la zona horaria del servidor, ademas de recargar nginx, o puede ser apache.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, estoy usando solo Node+Express+ Socket.io. Gracias

Comment: Eso lo deberías de poner en la pregunta para que tengas una mejor respuesta, de todas maneras, aquí hay información que te puede servir. https://itnext.io/node-express-letsencrypt-generate-a-free-ssl-certificate-and-run-an-https-server-in-5-minutes-a730fbe528ca

Comment: sisi, lo vi. Gracias!